# Can a moving electron produce a magnetic field stronger than what caused it to move in a circle

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons

We know that when an electron is made to enter a magnetic field, say $B_1$, with some velocity at a right angle to $B_1$, a force acts on it which makes it rotate in a circle. But a moving electron produces current which would have its own magnetic field. Let's call the rotating electron's field $B_2$. Can $B_2$ be greater than $B_1$? If yes, then under what conditions?

Comment: The field $B_2$ produced will be non-constant so it would be better to talk about it at a specific point, such as the centre of the circle.

Comment: Okay in that case is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go ahead and do the simplest analysis of this: we have a charge $q$ in a $B_0$ field aligned along say the $z$ axis. It starts with an initial velocity $v$ perpendicular to the $B_0$ axis. As is well known, this gives rise to circular motion at the gyrofrequency $\omega = \frac{qB_0}{m}$.

This orbiting electron produces a magnetic field. Treating the electron as a circular ring of current we see it has an equivalent current of $I = \frac{q\omega}{2\pi}$. By the Biot-Savart law that produces a current at the centre of the ccurrent loop of $B = \frac{\mu_0I}{2r}$.

Plugging this all together gives $B = \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{q^2\mu_0 / m }{r}B_0$. The scale $\lambda = e^2 \mu_0 / m _e$ for an electron produces the result $\lambda = 3.5\times10^{-14}m$, smaller than an electron's Compton wavelength. So the induced field is larger than the applied field for very tightly orbiting electrons, but the critical point is below the Compton wavelength and so we would need to analyse the situation better (with both relativity and quantum mechanics accounted for).

(PS the length scale $\lambda$ is the classical electron radius, up to dimensionless factors. That fact alone should suggest this is going to require non-classical physics.)

Answer (score 0):

The electron is smaller than 1E-18 m [1] [2] and maybe it is merely a point. Magnetic field of moving charged particle is given by

$$
\mathbf B = \mathbf v\times \mathbf E/c^2
$$
where $\mathbf v$ is velocity of the particle and $\mathbf E$ is its electric field.

According to Coulomb's law, electric field of a charged particle varies with distance from it as $\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}$, which means the closer to the particle, the higher the electric field. For point particle, there is no limit.

So as we go closer to the electron, the electric and magnetic field increases. If the electron has some radius, the maximum electric and magnetic field are limited but still extreme. At distance 1e-10 m (atom size) from the electron, the electric field strength is 140 GV/m, and if the electron is moving with 1/100 of speed of light, the magnetic induction is 5T, both of which are achievable field strengths in laboratory for a long time and large space region. At a distance 1E-15 m (nucleus size), the electric and magnetic fields are, hypothetically, 1e10 times higher than that, which is not achievable in laboratory by any means.

In any case, if near enough to the electron, the magnetic induction is much stronger than the maximum achieved magnetic induction  in laboratory (50T continually, ~ 100T in short bursts.)

[1] http://gabrielse.physics.harvard.edu/gabrielse/overviews/ElectronSubstructure/ElectronSubstructure.html (limit based on "low energy" experiments)

[2] https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0109138.pdf

Comment: Can you give a reference for the radius of $10^{-18}$ m as an upper limit ?

Comment: @my2cts I've added some references.

Comment: Great, thanks! This limit is much smaller than the Thompson radius.

Comment: Indeed, the Thomson scattering cross-section has nothing to do with size of electron charge distribution; the latter may be zero (point electron) but the Thomson scattering cross section will remain that of a disk with radius ~ 1e-15m.